# For what value of $c$ have $\bar{\theta}$ risk minimum.

Tags: probability

Let $f$ a density function such that

$$f(x)=\frac{2(\theta-x)}{\theta^2}\qquad ,0<x<\theta$$

Consider the estimators of $\theta$ of the form $\bar{\theta}=c\bar{x}$ where $c$ is constant.

For what value of $c$ have $\bar{\theta}$ risk minimum ?

**My attempt**

Note if $c=3$ then  $E[\bar{\theta}]=\theta$this implies if $c=3$ then $\bar{\theta}$ is unbiased.

We know by Cramer-Rao theorem

$V(\bar{\theta})\geq\frac{1}{N\times E(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}ln(f(x)))^2}$

Note

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}ln(f(x)))^2=\frac{(\theta-2x)^2}{\theta^2(\theta-x)^2}$

As $0<x<\theta$ then $\theta-2x<\theta$. this implies

$\frac{(\theta-2x)^2}{\theta^2(\theta-x)}<\frac{\theta^2}{\theta^2(\theta-x)}=\frac{1}{\theta-x}$

I need bound $\theta-x$ because i don't know how calculate  $E[\frac{1}{\theta-x}]$.

I'm stuck wit this exercise. i need help. Can someone help me?